# a fixed div inside another div

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have been struggling with this problem for over 2 hours,
Is there a way to make a div fixed while it is inside a bigger div.
When I scroll I want to keep the right part not scrolling.

[image: scroll image]

So my question is, is there a way to do this without jquery?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code? What have you tried? This should be able to be accomplished just using CSS.

Comment: it is a little hard to isolate the code for jsfiddle so here is the link http://www.noties.me/index.php, if you click on the januari first date you can see the div i'm talking about

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to position the inner div `absolute`ly:

```
.outerDiv {
    position: relative;
    /* give it some height */
}
.contentDiv {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.innerDiv {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wSxss/

---

Adjust the positioning values according to your needs.

Comment: yes I am looking for that, lets see if I can apply it to my code as I have already used position absolute.

Comment: for some reason I still can't let it scroll, I wonder if this has to do because i'm letting the whole popup box scroll instead of only the left part (time and info) of the div.

Comment: @user1213904 - Not sure I'm following you. Does my fiddle work for you?

Comment: yes the fiddle does work however i feel that it isn't usable on my code because of my whole popup window scroll. its hard to isolate the code so if you could take a peek on http://www.noties.me/index.php, it shows up when you click on the first of januari block

Answer (score 0):

[This fiddle demonstrates the following solution](http://jsfiddle.net/HgUgE/4/):

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="scroller></div>
    <div class="fixed"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS (example of key parts)**

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.scroller {
    padding-right: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.fixed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 160px; /* .scroller padding minus the right offset to accomodate scroll bar and minus any real separation between it and the scroller */
}
```